# Map Reduce out collection on different mongo instance

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-java

Is it possible to create Map Reduce out collection on different mongod instance. Idea is to perform map reduce on different mongod (only for read) & create  or modify(in case of incremental MR) the map reduce out collection on different mongod (write) instance.

Comment: No, It's not possible. We managed to do it by writing our own component.

Answer (score 0):

You could with the use of sharding.

If you have two shards and shard tag all docs in the input collection to shard-1. Then use a sharded output on the map reduce, and shard tag all the output docs to shard-2.